# What processor architecture is in a 230GMULps KPU design?

Tags: microprocessor, computer-architecture, processor

While AI products are becoming popular recently, when looking at the "Seeed Studio Grove AI HAT for Edge Computing Artificial Intelligence Board" it mentions a RISC-V, a 230GMULps 16-bit KPU (Neural Network Processor), a FPU, etc.

What is this "230GMULps"? What could be the processor architecture in it if it can be illustrated by an example?

Update: I initially thought of a specific model. As comments indicated that it is the number of multiplications, so I updated the question to ask for an example architecture.

Comment: GMul = billion multiplications, so 230 GMULPs = 230000000000 16-bit multiplications per second.

Comment: Ah! Then how does that relates/translates to 1TOPS? The processor claims 1TOPS.

Comment: A complete guess, but ops might count things other than multiplication (e.g. the addition and accumulation that are also needed on a neural network and are likely cheaper/easier than a multiplication)

Comment: @nanofarad Can you give an example of an architecture that supports the guess and put it as an answer?

Comment: I cannot at the moment. It is merely a guess based on past experience without any specific architecture I can think of offhand to formally justify it, so I'd rather not post a full answer that I can't fully justify.

Comment: "Giga Multiplications Per Second" (GMULPS) measures the system throughput. Sometimes you see Giga Connection Updates Per Second (GCUPS) used as the metric, but it depends on the batch size. So some prefer a general throughput metric that can be applied to any batch size. I think they are claiming several thousand parallel multipliers. But why don't you just ask the seller?

Comment: But I think the literature is not very consistent on exactly what a multiplier is. Some appear to consider their inputs as the binary result of a threshold comparation. In those cases, a multiplier is just an AND gate. In others, they consider real number notation, so a multiplier there is different. You really need to ask those folks what their term means. But then, you need to study the AI literature, beforehand, too.

Comment: I know we should get the information from the vendor. It will take a lot of business interactions based on our past experience.

Comment: @minghua the question you've asked has no actual utility at all beyond "marketing bragging rights" - for anything *meaningful* you're going to have to specify your need or ask the manufacturer if this could meet it.  Realistically the product won't be of any use to you unless it has good documentation or a responsive manufacturer.

Comment: @ChrisStratton , That may sounds like you are right, fully understand. It is actually how I try to understand what goes into an AI engine while we are designing a system, that may be an assembled from available chipsets, or a custom asic. In the assembled design, I need to create a requirements. For an asic, I'll need to decide what blocks shall be put into it. Thanks for your sharing the view though.

Comment: I have studied a few open-source asic architectures, as well as the nvidia tensors. It has always been tricky to figure out how the capability numbers match to the internal architecture.

Comment: There’s a lot of puffery in the AI industry. The most-abused metric might very well be TOPs. It’s not easy to actually achieve that number in practice. The more meaningful number is inferences/s for a given network. So, the network and the throughout you need should guide your decision, not TOPs.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the input in comments. I'll post an example as an answer when I figure out someday.